# How to avoid calling select query twice for difference in only one condition

Tags: sql, database, performance, db2, exists

The below mentioned queries(outer and inner query) are similar except for one clause T2.COL2=(Temporary/Permanent). To accommodate this clause the select is executed twice, leading to performance degrade. Can we merge the inner query with the outer one and avoid using exists and also avoid calling select twice.

The below query returns only one record where T1.COL2='Temporary'. Modified query should also return only one result.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.COL1='Rajesh' AND T1.COL2='Temporary' 
AND EXISTS (                                            
     SELECT 'Y'                                             
      FROM TABLE1 T2 WHERE T2.COL1='Rajesh' AND T2.COL2='Permanant')
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM (SELECT T1.*, MIN(COL2) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.COL1) as MIN_COL2
      FROM TABLE1 T1 
      WHERE T1.COL1 = 'Rajesh' AND T1.COL2 IN ('Permanent', 'Temporary')
     ) T1
WHERE MIN_COL2 = 'Permanent' AND T1.COL2 = 'Temporary';
```

Comment: @user6804978 . . . It should.